# Reassembly of Ethernet packet from USB URBs

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I am trying to figure out where is the code or module that reassemble Ethernet packet from USB URBs.
Ethernet frames are about 1500 bytes in size—about 3 USB 2.0 packets (Bulk).
So on the RX, there is a need to reassemble the 3 URBs to 1 Ethernet frame, I couldn't find the module that do it.

I use Linux 2.6.39/ARM,EHCI host controller.

BR, Tal